# How to add a super-category to axis in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a heatmap with multiple levels of categorization on one axis, i.e. marking that Ideal, Premium, and Very Good diamonds are "Great" while Good and Fair diamonds are just "OK."

I know I could use color, but I want it to work in black and white, and I can't use `sec_axis` because it's not a one-to-one mapping. (I tried using `scale_y_discrete(sec.axis = sec_axis(rating))` and `sec.axis = rating` but both gave me an unused argument error.)

Here's some representative data with the code to make a regular heatmap:

```r
library(ggplot2)

diamond_rating <- tibble(cut = factor("Fair", "Good", "Very Good", "Premium", "Ideal"), rating = c("OK", "OK", "Great", "Great", "Great"))

diamonds %>% 
  count(color, cut) %>%  
  left_join(diamond_rating) %>%
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = color, y = cut)) +
    geom_tile(mapping = aes(fill = n))
```

But I can't figure out how to add a super-axis, as it were, or even how/where it should fit into ggplot2's grammar of graphics.

Comment: Would splitting the plot into multiple facets be sufficient? ie. adding `+ facet_wrap(.~ Rating)` to your current code.

Comment: Where are you trying to add this grouping? Can you add an example of something similar? You might add a categorical variable that lumps cut into 2 groups, then facet on that

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this code is helpful. By employing `facet_wrap` and some tweaking in `theme` you can have a graph with supercategories.

```
diamond_rating <- tibble(cut = c("Fair", "Good", "Very Good", "Premium", "Ideal"), rating = c("OK", "OK", "Great", "Great", "Great"))

library(ggplot2)

diamonds %>% 
  count(color, cut) %>%  
  left_join(diamond_rating) %>%
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = color, y = cut)) +
  geom_tile(mapping = aes(fill = n)) +
  facet_wrap(~rating, scales = "free_y", nrow = 2, strip.position = "left") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(strip.placement = "outside",
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        panel.spacing = unit(0, "lines"),
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "grey"))
```

[image]